# In Notepad++ How can I identify/count records that don't meet a certain length requirement?

Tags: notepad++, text-processing

I have a file in Notepad++ that has 200,000 rows and each row needs to be a certain length (`2500`). However I know some rows are shorter or longer than that. How can I find out how many rows are breaking this rule and which rows those are?

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex search like this to find and/or count all the incorrect lines:

```
^.{0,2499}$|^.{2501,}$
```

It basically finds lines with `0` to `2499` of any characters (`.`), `^` marks the start and `$` the end of line. The 2nd alternative finds lines with at least `2501` characters.

Make sure that `. matches newline` option is **deselected**.

Comment: Destroy666 you are a lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: @MIGUEL no problem, if it helped, please make sure to mark the answer as helpful on the left to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to find lines that don't have 2500 character :

- Find What: `^(?!.{2500}$).+`

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (?!         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't
    .{2500}     # 2500 any characters
    $           # until end of line
  )           # end lookahead
  .+          # match the whole line
```